# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'lat')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

el archivo Success.jsx es un componente React que representa una página de confirmación de compra exitosa. Dentro de este componente, se importa un hook personalizado llamado usePositionStack que se utiliza para obtener la ubicación del usuario a partir de una dirección proporcionada, devuelve las coordenadas como un array de dos elementos. Además, el componente importa un componente llamado Map de React Leaflet, que se utiliza para mostrar un mapa con la ubicación obtenida.

success.jsx

```
    import React, { useContext } from 'react';
    import AppContext from '../context/AppContext';
    import Map from '../components/Map';
    import '../styles/components/Success.css'
    import usePositionStack from '../hooks/usePositionStack';

    const Success = () => {
        const { state } = useContext(AppContext);
        const { buyer } = state;
        // const address = `${buyer[0].address}, ${buyer[0].city}, ${buyer[0].state}, ${buyer[0].country}`;
        const location = usePositionStack()
        console.log(location);

        return (  
            <div className="Success">
                <div className="Success-content">
                    <h2>{`${buyer.name}, Gracias por tu compra`}</h2>
                    <span>Tu pedido llegara en 3 dias a tu direccion</span>
                    <div className="Success-map">
                        <Map data={location}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
    export default Success;
```

usePositionStarck.jsx

```
    import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import axios from 'axios';

    //"http://api.positionstack.com/v1/forward ? access_key = rwc6l00gdwzv24l8c7877scitwa2rtj2 & query = 1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, Washington DC, Estados Unidos"
    const url = 'http://api.positionstack.com/v1/forward';

    const usePositionStack = () => {
        const [map, setMap] = useState([]);

        const params = new URLSearchParams({
            access_key: 'rwc6l00gdwzv24l8c7877scitwa2rtj2',
            query: '1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, Washington DC, Estados Unidos'
          }).toString();

        useEffect(() => {
            async function fetchData() {
                const response = await axios(`${url}?${params}`)
                const result = [response.data.data[0].latitude,response.data.data[0].longitude]
                console.log(result);
                setMap(result)
            }
            fetchData();
        }, []); 

        return map;
    }
    export default usePositionStack;
```

Map.jsx

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet'
    import { Icon } from 'leaflet'
    import '../styles/components/Map.css';

    // el atributo center de MapContainer debe recibir un arreglo como el de abajo (position)
    //const position = [38.897675, -77.036547]

    const ChartMap = ({data}) => {
        console.log(data);
        return (
            <>
                { data != null &&
                    <MapContainer center={data} zoom={13}>
                        <TileLayer
                            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                        />
                        <Marker position={data} >
                            <Popup icon={Icon}>
                                A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
                            </Popup>
                        </Marker>
                    </MapContainer>
                }
            </>
        );
    };
    export default ChartMap;
```

Primero en los console.log aparece [] y despues aparecer el error siguiente:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'lat')
        at Object.project (leaflet-src.js:1763:45)
        at Object.latLngToPoint (leaflet-src.js:1600:42)
        at NewClass.project (leaflet-src.js:4094:29)
        at NewClass.latLngToLayerPoint (leaflet-src.js:4116:31)
        at NewClass.update (leaflet-src.js:7829:26)
        at NewClass.onAdd (leaflet-src.js:7748:10)
        at NewClass._layerAdd (leaflet-src.js:6844:10)
        at NewClass.whenReady (leaflet-src.js:4589:15)
        at NewClass.addLayer (leaflet-src.js:6902:10)
        at addLayer (layer.js:19:19)

    The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef(ContainerComponent)> component:
        at ContainerComponent (webpack://platzi-conf-merch/./node_modules/@react leaflet/core/lib/component.js?:15:41)
        at div
        at MapContainerComponent (webpack://platzi-conf-merch/./node_modules/react leaflet/lib/MapContainer.js?:25:34)
        at ChartMap (webpack://platzi-conf-merch/./src/components/Map.jsx?:24:19)
```

[image: xjn7F.png]

y despues del error ya me sale en un console.log el resultado que mando usePosition.js [38.897675, -77.036547].
[image: dHMRj.png]

Siento que primero me da un valor nulo cuando usa async. Ayudenme, por favor

Una de las cosas que intente es crear como una condicion en en Map.jsx

```
{ data != null &&
     <MapContainer center={data} zoom={13}>

     </MapContainer>
}
```

Pero cuando no uso usePositionStack y pongo los datos ya definidos(hardcodeado) entonces si funciona como por ejemplo:

```
const position = [38.897675, -77.036547]
const ChartMap = () => {
    return (
        <MapContainer center={position} zoom={13}>
          //demas codigo
        </MapContainer>
    );
};
```

Comment: estas llamando a fetchdata sin un await..

Comment: me sale este error: react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: useEffect must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up.
It looks like you wrote useEffect(async () => ...) or returned a Promise. Instead, write the async function inside your effect and call it immediately:

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    // You can await here
    const response = await MyAPI.getData(someId);
    // ...
  }
  fetchData();
}, [someId]); // Or [] if effect doesn't need props or state

Comment: lo puse asi: useEffect(async () => {
        const response = await axios(`${url}?${params}`)
        const result = [response.data.data[0].latitude,response.data.data[0].longitude]
        console.log(result);
        setMap(result)
    }, []);

Answer (score 0):

Como bien te comentó el colega en los comentarios. Las llamadas a `APIS` deben realizarse mediante *asincronía*.

Importante también es que una de las muchas [reglas de los hooks](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), es que precisamente éstos no pueden implementarse directamente con un `async/await`, sino que debes crear una función dentro de `useEffect` que sea asíncrona.

```
useEffect(() => {
   (async () => {
      const response = await axios...
      // resto del codigo
   })()
})
```

De esta manera, realizas llamada inmediatamente cuando se renderice el componente en cuestión.

Cualquier duda, nos comentas.

Saludos

Comment: me sale el mismo error. pero ahora tengo otro problema: 

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 () Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError`

`code: "ERR_BAD_REQUEST"`

`config: {transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}

message: "Request failed with status code 403"

name: "AxiosError" Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x'). `

Me aparece Access Restricted - Your current Subscription Plan does not support HTTPS Encryption